# Adding a FOREIGN KEY but says the column does not exists when it does?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I have created two tables

EMPLOYEE

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
    emp_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT  NOT NULL, 
    first_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
    address VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (emp_id)
);
```

TEAM

```
CREATE TABLE team (
    team_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT  NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(20),
    manager_id INT (20),
    PRIMARY KEY (team_id)
);
```

I am trying to add a add a foreign key:

```
ALTER TABLE employee ADD FOREIGN KEY (manager_id) REFERENCES team(manager_id);
```

It is giving me an error telling me that the column does not exist

> ERROR 1072 (42000): Key column 'manager_id' doesn't exist in table

But it does show when I `Describe team`

```
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| team_id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| manager_id | int(20)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: It should be `REFERENCES employee(emp_id);`

Comment: column `manager_id`  does not exists in table `employee`

Comment: If you don't tell us why you wrote that, how are we supposed to help you? The problem is in your expectations, so tell us what they are. Also the error message is very clear--there is no manager_id in employee. Also this is a faq. Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS This shows no research. PS Read the manual about functionality you are using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Column `manager_id`  does not exists in table `employee`.

Something like this would be more meaningful:

```
ALTER TABLE team ADD FOREIGN KEY (manager_id) REFERENCES employee(emp_id);
```

Possibly, you also build a table to represent the relationship between employees and teams. As of now, nothing in your schema can be used to relate an employee to one or several teams.

Comment: Thanks for the reply when I run this code it executes but I can not see it when I `DESCRIBE employee `. It also says this `Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0`

Comment: @Liam: the constraint I suggested is on table `team`. Try `describe team` instead.

Comment: :Ok i see it now it says `MUL`, I thought I was adding it to the TABLE employee so that it could link these two tables together